# How to programatically create a ViewMenu in Eclipse RCP 4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

```
    @Inject
    public Widget(MPart part)
    {
        viewMenu = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createMenu();
        part.getMenus().add(viewMenu);
    }
```

When I create a Menu or ViewMenu through the .e4xmi file and check the class of the objects, they both return the same classes.  The MMenuFactory only allows me to create an MMenu object.  How would I created a ViewMenu or convert an MMenu object to a ViewMenu?

*NOTE:* The above code does not provide me with a view menu.  Though, when I create a ViewMenu through the .e4xmi file, it shows up in list returned from the getMenus() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the tag `ViewMenu` to the menu:

```
viewMenu = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createMenu();

viewMenu.getTags().add("ViewMenu");

// TODO add menu items

part.getMenus().add(viewMenu);
```

Note: The view will not be shown if it does not contain some menu items

Comment: Despite adding and confirming the addition of menu items, the menu still does not display.  I set it to visible as well.  Any additional suggestions?

Comment: It works for me using Eclipse Neon. Are you doing something like trying to create this after the part has been rendered?

Comment: Well, it displays now.  Thank you for your time and help.